# Bookmark page in xcode6 - Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xcode6

I'm trying to create a bookmark page for my app. basically, I want to be able to click on a button in my UIViewController, and have the url of the website I'm currently viewing be saved as a cell in a UITableViewController. The problem is I'm not so sure of the best way to implement this.

I think the way to do it would be to have a mutable array in my tableviewcontroller which I've created here:

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

 @interface FavoriteViewController : UITableViewController

 @property (strong, atomic) NSMutableArray *tableItems;

 @end
```

I could then use the button in the viewController to populate the array. However when I try something like this:

```
- (IBAction)fave:(id)sender {
[FavoriteViewController.tableItems addObject:[NSString self.faveURL]];   
}
```

I receive an error that property tableItems is not found on FavoriteViewController. Not sure why this is. Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access properties through object instead of directly calling by class name.

```
- (IBAction)fave:(id)sender {
        // If accessing from other class
        FavoriteViewController *favVC = ------
        [favVC.tableItems addObject:[NSString self.faveURL]];   
  }

- (IBAction)fave:(id)sender {
        // If accessing from same class where you defined your variable
        [self.tableItems addObject:[NSString self.faveURL]];   
}
```

If you want to access using class name then you have to static/class methods instead of properties.

Comment: Ok. I tried out the first of your options, but my FavoriteViewController doesn't seem to be affected by the button presses. I'm guess because the button presses are only affecting an instance of FavoriteViewController and that instance is not the same instance appearning in my app. Any way to fix this? Do I need to use static methods?

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.tableItems addObject:[NSString self.faveURL]];
```

You're accessing a class variable with your current code, but `tableItems` is an instance variable. So if the function `fave` is in the FavoriteViewController class, then you need to reference `self` when accessing the instance variable.